# How to include js lib files only when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I've a main js file `app.js`. I'm using this file in 5 different pages.

In `app.js`, I've used 3 different library files which are needed only in certain pages. So I've included those js files in only those single pages. (Not in all 5 pages).

In my `app.js`, I've:

```
$('#describe').redactor():
```

a library file for rich text.

So If I load any other page which doesn't use the `redactor.js` file, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).redactor is not a function
```

So, how can I avoid calling this function in the `app.js` file?

Comment: You have to include everything all the time or user server side code to include pertinent libraries.

Comment: Is your `#describe` element on pages that do not need the redactor library?

Comment: this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009446/load-js-when-visible

Comment: You may want to look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or similar.

Comment: Nope. So I tried something like this: `var describe=document.getElementById('describe');` and called the function only `if (describe)`. But didn't work

Comment: It sounds to me like you haven't included the `redactor.js` file on every page that includes the `#describe` element, or you're attempting to call the function incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to test for the presence of elements before calling the function on them. This breaks jQuery's chainability:

```
var $describe;
$describe = $('#describe');
if ($describe.length) {
    $describe.redactor();
}
```

Of course this assumes that `#describe` will only be present on pages that have included the `jQuery.redactor` plugin.

Another way is to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) (or similar tools) to handle your dependency management.

Comment: "Ths breaks jQuery's chainability":- Is it a good or bad thing?

Comment: It's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
if (!$.redactor) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://link-to-js-file.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for you project but you should look into using  [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) .  One of there sample projects can be found [here](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)